# How to correctly invoke cmdlet from another cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a number of cmdlets written. The one I'm currently working on I'd like to call my other cmdlets. I'm attempting this like so:

```
//Calling cmdlet
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    Cmdlet1 _cmdlet1 = new Cmdlet1();
    _cmdlet1.configFilePath = this.configFilePath; //set a few parameters the cmdlet will need
    _cmdlet1.useConfigFile = true; //and one more
    _cmdlet1.Invoke();

    Cmdlet2 _cmdlet2 = new Cmdlet2();
    _cmdlet2.configFilePath = this.configFilePath; //set a few parameters again
    _cmdlet2.useConfigFile = true; //one more
    _cmdlet2.Invoke();
}
```

However, when I run "Calling cmdlet" from powershell, nothing happens. There are no errors, none of the code I've written in my other cmdlets is run. There's a number of `WriteObject` calls in `Cmdlet1` and `Cmdlet2`, shouldn't I be able to see those if the cmdlets are actually being run? Though I should mention that that's obviously not the only thing I'm checking to verify that they're being successfully called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects you are writing with WriteObject are being returned via the `Invoke()` method call. Iterate over the results of that call to get the individual objects from the cmdlet invocation e.g.:

```
foreach (var result in _cmdlet1.Invoke())
{
    ...
}
```

See this [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/ms568248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.